# Hexagon, from vertex to midpoint of a side.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

${ABCDEF}$ is a regular hexagon with side length $2$ units, ${T}$ is the midpoint of side ${CD}$, what will be the length of the line ${AT}$?

Comment: What have you tried, you don't show any attempt to solve the problem.  You should also include a labelled figure showing the hexagon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ABCDEF$ is a regular hexagon, therefore, $AB=BC=CD=DE=EF=FA$ and all internal angles are equal to $120^{\circ}$. $T$ is the midpoint of side $CD$, therefore, $CT=DT$. $AB=2$.

$\triangle{ABC}$ - an isosceles triangle, $\implies$ $\angle{BAC}=\angle{BCA}=30^{\circ}$, $\implies$ $\angle{ACT}=90^{\circ}$ and $AC=2\sqrt{3}$, $\implies$ $AT=(AC^{2}+CT^{2})^{0.5}=\sqrt{13}$, $\implies$ $\bbox[lightgreen]{AT=\sqrt{13}}$.